# Connect Test Controller on Azure VM to on-premises TFS to run automated Coded UI Test

Tags: powershell, azure, tfs, coded-ui-tests, lab-management

I have the following scenario:

- TFS On-Premises installation, 2013.4 with Release Management and Build Server.
- Azure hosted environment where the application gets deployed to with Release Management vNext PowerShell
- Single Windows Server 2012R2 machine in Azure that's used as a Client to run webbased Coded UI tests.

I've used the following blog for the setup: 
[How to run Microsoft Test Manager Suite in vNext Deployment](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-run-Microsoft-Test-Manager-Suite-in-vNext-Deployment.aspx)

I have configured a Test Controller and Agent on the Client machine in Azure. I can create a Standard Lab environment from MTM, run a release from RM and see a new test run appear in MTM.

However, the test run keeps waiting in the status 'Waiting for Test Controller'.

What have I done wrong? Any pointers on how to fix my configuration?

Comment: look on the event log on your test controller machine for any errors/warnings.

Comment: @DylanSmith there are no errors/warnings in the event log

Comment: Fire up the Test Controller Configuration tool verify your settings, and hit Apply.  Make sure all the config checks still come back green.